# Music directory on Nexus 5 emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, ddms

How can I push music to the Nexus 5 (4.4.2) emulator for testing? With Nexus 4 emulator I used DDMS to push to storage/sdcard/Music. But my actual Nexus 5 uses mnt/shell/emulated/0/Music. These folders don't show up on the emulator. (Nor does sdcard/Music.) If I try to create them with DDMS I get a read-only error.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no Nexus 5 emulator. There is only the emulator. If you are getting read-only errors, perhaps you did not add external storage to the emulator image.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I meant Nexus 5 AVD... But I'm still unclear about where to push music files to. I added 200 MiB Internal Storage and 50 MiB SD storage (even though the Nexus 5 doesn't have SD storage).

Comment: The Nexus 5 does indeed have external storage. While the AVD tools still refer to it as an "SD card", it is really setting up external storage. You may need to create the `Music` directory.